# What does "he is said to be polite" mean?

Tags: passive-voice

Does

> He is said to be polite.

mean:

> People say that he is polite.

or

> People say him to be polite.

?

Comment: **Passive voice**: He is said to be polite. **Active voice**: People say that he is polite.

Answer (score 1):

It means

> People say that he is a polite person.

I guess that in order to say that he is routinely asked to be polite, we would say just that,

> He is always asked to be polite.

Or even, in a stricter manner,

> He is constantly told to be polite (by his parents).

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, the first assumption is close to what it actually means.

> "He is said to be polite."

This means that *'he'* is rather polite to others and other acknowledge the fact that he is, indeed, polite. This can be translated as:

> *He is known to be polite.*

Consider the sentence: *"Norway is said to be very beautiful."*

This means that the general opinion about Norway is that the country is very beautiful. Similarly, you could interpret what your sentence means.

Answer (score 1):

> He is said to be polite

This could have two meanings:

- you have met him and think that he is quite rude, but you are too polite to say so
- you have not met him, and are reporting what other people say: "other people say that he is polite".

Here is another example of the first usage. A man is sitting opposite two Norwegians at a dinner party. They ask him what he thinks of Norway: he went there once and detested it, but he is too polite to say so. Instead, he says "Norway is said to be very beautiful". The Norwegians are happy, and the man has not compromised his integrity by lying.